# .filter for specific tag in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My array:

```js
{
  "items": [{
    "url": "XXX",
    "title": "XXX",
    "tags": [
      "One",
      "Two"
    ]
  }]
}
```

I am trying to filter out and return items only where tags has "Two"

```
const loadArticles = async () => {
fetch(mediumRssFeed, { headers: { Accept: "application/json" } })
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => data.items.filter((item) => ???))
.then((newArticles) => newArticles.slice(0, MAX_ARTICLES))
.then((articles) => setArticles(articles))
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

I assume it is this line:

```
.then((data) => data.items.filter((item) => ???))
```

How do I revise so that it only return those items with a tag of "Two"?

Comment: You only need to add `then` when the method returns a promise. The code inside the last 2 `then` should be moved inside the `.then((data) => data.items.filter... )` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Array.prototype.filter()` method to filter out items that do not have the tag "Two". You can use the `Array.prototype.includes()` method to check if the tags array includes "Two".

***You can revise the line like this:***

> .then((data) => data.items.filter((item) =>
> item.tags.includes("Two")))

This filters the items array and only keeps the items that have **"Two"** in their tags array.

Answer (score 1):

If the tags must contain "Two", then the following should work

`data.items.filter((item) => item.tags.includes("Two")`.

You can also use object destructuring to slightly shorten

`data.items.filter(({ tags }) => tags.includes("Two")`.